# Creating Resources object not from Activity

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I tried to create Resources object in my custom class in constructor:

```
    public class Morze {

public Morze() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
}
```

}

But Intellij idea cannot resolve method "getResources". However, code

```
Resources resources = getResources();
```

correctly work in onCreate method of Activity. What can I do in order to use this code in my own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> correctly work in onCreate method of Activity. What can I do in order
>   to use this code in my own class?

Resources you are able to retrieve only from Context (each Activity extends from Context this is reason why it works without problem in Activities) so to order to obtain resources from raw class you need to pass Context via constructor for example:

```
public class Morze {

   private Context c;       

   public Morze(Context c) {
      this.c = c;
      Resources resources = this.c.getResources();
   }
}
```

Or you can create some method for example init() that will initialise required objects:

```
public void init(Context c) {
   this.c = c;
   this.resources = this.c.getResources();
}
```

But solution with constructor is *"more natural"* than second approach.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get Resources object like this in a class which is not an Activity, instead, you have to give context to Morze class for this-

```
public class Morze {

public Morze(Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
}
```